# How can I resize a view, while proportionally resizing it's subviews?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a custom segue, where the first view controller shrinks a little and the second one slides over top of it. Here's what I have for segue implementation:

```
override func perform() {
    let firstView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
    let secondView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow

    secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenSize.height, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
    window?.insertSubview(secondView, aboveSubview: firstView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {

        // BEGIN RELEVANT PORTION
        let offset: CGFloat = 20

        firstView.frame = CGRectMake(offset, offset, screenSize.width - (offset * 2), screenSize.height - (offset * 2))
        firstView.autoresizesSubviews = true
        firstView.layoutIfNeeded()
        // END RELEVANT PORTION

    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 1, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

This produces a result like this:

[image: gif showing the result of the above code]

This is already really great, but not what I intended. I need the subviews ("Hi, I'm Matt." label and button) to resize proportionally to the superview, as if the entire view were falling down on the *z* axis.

I am using Auto Layout.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Do you want label and button shrink with respect to its superView ?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. :)

Comment: did you added the Constraints on label and button with its super view ?

Comment: Yes. They both have centre in superview constraints, with a constant on the horizontal centre for the label

Comment: I have added the answer below, tell me if its not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem using `CGAffineTransform`.

```
override func perform() {
    let firstView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
    let secondView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!
    let screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow

    secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, screenSize.height, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
    window?.insertSubview(secondView, aboveSubview: firstView)

    firstView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    firstView.layer.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {

        print(firstView.frame)

        let offset: CGFloat = 25
        let offsetX = 2 * (offset / firstView.frame.width)
        let offsetY = 2 * (offset * (firstView.frame.height / firstView.frame.width) / firstView.frame.height)

        let transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1 - offsetX, 1 - offsetY)
        firstView.transform = transform
        firstView.layer.position = CGPoint(x: offset, y: offset)

    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.05, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {

        secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)

        }) { finished -> Void in
            self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Thanks for your help anyway, everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Applying transform is a good view to achieve it.

There's another way with which you can achieve it with no risk of modifying the first viewcontroller's view's frame. Take a snapshot of the first viewcontroller's view and use it instead of the view itself. You can use the following method in *UIView* to take a snapshot:

```
- (UIView *)snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:(BOOL)afterUpdates;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it using your Scenario in my Xcode now you have to follow these steps

```
1- Give UIButton & UILabel Leading and Trailing Space to their SuperView
2- Make UIButton central Vertically
3- Give Vertical Space from UIButton to UILabel
```

> **Important:**
>
> Hope it will work because then trick is that you have to give leading & trailing space to super View to make the InnerViews Shrink or expand w.r.t its superView

Answer (score 1):

One way around can be:

- Give both of them(Label and button) width constraints.
- Make outlets of both width constraints. **constraintWidthLabel**, **constraintWidthButton**
- You can make outlet of a constraint like this

[image]

- When you perform segue you have to make these width constraints to zero with animation.

  ```
  UIView.animateWithDuration(2, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {

  // BEGIN RELEVANT PORTION
  let offset: CGFloat = 20
  constraintWidthLabel.constant = 0
  constraintWidthButton.constant = 0;

  firstView.frame = CGRectMake(offset, offset, screenSize.width - (offset * 2), screenSize.height - (offset * 2))
  firstView.autoresizesSubviews = true
  firstView.layoutIfNeeded()
  // END RELEVANT PORTION

  }, completion: nil)
  ```